# Continuously differentiable functions on open convex set in $\mathbf{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

This is related to a few problems I was given in class, so please try not to post full answers, and hints/methods of proof instead.

I have been told that if we are given an open subset $X\subset\mathbf{R}^n$ that is convex, and a $C^1$-function $\varphi:X\to\mathbf{R}^n,$ that if
$$\|(D\varphi)(x)-I\|<1$$ for every $x\in X,$ we can show the following:

1. $\varphi(X)$ is also open. (**Proved**)
2. $\varphi$ is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism from $X$ to $\varphi(X).$ (**Proved**)

Firstly, I thought to start from the following result ($k:=b-a$) which was given as a problem to the class (and I have proved as another exercise).
$$\|\varphi(b)-\varphi(a)-k\|\leq\int^1_0\|(D\varphi)(a+\lambda k)-I\|\|k\|d\lambda.$$ Using this I could show that $\varphi$ is one-to-one without a lot of fuss. I also know that since the matrix $(D\varphi)(x)$ is $n\times n$ that if it obeys that inequality above, it should be nonsingular (I have also shown this). I've got the injective property now, and I think I've now got something close to surjectivity, but I'm having a bit of trouble sealing the deal, as it were.

Could someone please just lend me a hand with the method for completing the proof of these two? Thanks in advance for any help.

Edit: I believe since $\varphi$ is a function and I know it is injective, then if I consider only the range of $\varphi$ instead of the whole $\mathbf{R}^n,$ I should have a surjection as well (since it's a function) and hence $\varphi$ is a bijection between $X$ and $\varphi(X)$. I think I'm correct in thinking so, so let me know if I'm on the right track here.

Second edit: For statement 1. since $X\subset\mathbf{R}^n$ and $\varphi$ is a continuous injective continuous map, then $\varphi(X)$ is open. So simple, don't know what I was thinking.

Final edit: Because the derivative matrix is invertible and $\varphi$ is injective the inverse is a $C^1$-function from $\varphi(X)$ to $X,$ and we get a diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer for my own question:

1. $X$ is open, $\varphi$ is $C^1$ and $(D\varphi)(x)$ is invertible for any $x\in X.$ Then can show that $\varphi(X)$ is also open.
2. Since $\varphi$ is also injective $\varphi^{-1}:\varphi(X)\to X$ is a $C^1$-function as well and is differentiable with derivative $\left(\varphi^\prime(\varphi^{-1}(s))\right)^{-1},$ so the two sets are diffeomorphic.